# Switch case within foreach loop duplicating results - php

Tags: php, duplicates

The below query is producing duplicate results for me:

```
foreach($roles as $role){ 
      if (($role == "Lead") or ($role == "developer") or ($role == "cms"))
          {
           <img src="https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/product/dslr/em1mk3/sample.html" />
          }
     else 
          {
           <p>No image</p>
          }
        }
```

in this query, for people who has multiple roles like - Lead and CMS, see duplicate output of t he images. What could be the better way to handle this?

Comment: That code doesn't produce a parse error for you?

Comment: Maybe you want to break the loop after finding a match.

Comment: @brombeer it's just a sample code. I have my codebase similar to this structure

Comment: Just write a utility function that takes `$roles` and returns a boolean.

Comment: Can you pls point me to some example? sorry...newbie here

Answer (score 1):

Just write a utility function:

```
function shouldShowImage($roles)
{
    foreach($roles as $role)
    {
        if(($role == "Lead") or ($role == "developer") or ($role == "cms"))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if(shouldShowImage($roles))
    echo '<img src="...">';
else
    echo '<p>No image</p>';
```

Comment: let me try this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of this code is that the logic is broken. You have multipe cases (Lead, developer, cms) but only want to match one of them. The same problem occurs when **not** matching logic is supposed to be run.
The first idea is to leave the loop as soon as a role matches. This is what Kevin Y said. And it's the same what the utility function does (because of the `return` inside the loop). But it's not the best idea. Let's take a look:

```
    // Not good! Just for explanation
    foreach ($roles as $role) { 
        if (($role == "Lead") or ($role == "developer") or ($role == "cms")) {
            echo "whatever";
            break;
        } else {
            echo "somewhatelse";
            // we should break here but can't for logical reasons
        }
    }
```

In this example, we leave the loop when a role match is found. But what if the role does **not** match? May be it will **not match** multiple times. So you get multiple "no-matching-image". This is not what you want. Unfortunately, we can't leave the loop in case of no match because we have to test more cases...

So, when you think again what you want, you come to this result:
If **one** of **multiple** cases match, show a particular image (and stop testing other cases). If not, show a different image.
Hehe, this sounds like using an array!

```
    // Should be better
    $match_roles = ["Lead", "developer", "cms"];
    $match = false;
    
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if (in_array($role, $match_roles)) {
            $match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    echo (true === $match) ? "one_image" : "another_image";
```

By the way: You can extend matching cases in this code very easily, just by adding more elements to the $match_roles array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This logic is partially working. it doesn't work when 2 different roles are selected. Meaning: if someone has "Lead" it breaks there. Doesn't check for the next "developer" or "cms" role. any help?

Comment: Well, now you are confusing me. In your very first post, you said that the problem was that users get an particular image **multiple** times if they have **multiple** roles and you want to show this image only once. I understand that you want to show an image if **one** of a set of roles matches (this is what my code does). It's a matter of logic, again. What do do really want?

Comment: Right. I want to show image if there is atleast one match. But let's say when the image is created for all 3 roles and we have 2 users one of them is Lead and one is developer. Only the Lead is seeing the image. Developer can't see one since the loop stops at the first match itself.

Comment: Since each user should log in separately, the loop runs for each user again and will not stop after first test for the second user. If it does not work for developer, may be you should check the spelling of the roles. "Developer" is not the same as "developer".